# tikz draw plot not correct

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am trying to plot a naca0012 airfoil profile by its analytic function ( [cf wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA_airfoil) ) using tikz and I can't understand why I get the following results. I precise that I get the same results if I use gnuplot in tikz `\draw plot function`. It seems to badly compute the 4 first percent of the plot. If I change to `domain=0.:0.05`, I also get the 4 first percent of `domain=0.:0.05` wrong.

what am I wrong ? Should I specified a tikz option somehow ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
  \draw[step=.02,gray,very thin] (-0.1,-0.1) grid (1.1,0.15);

  \draw[color=red,domain=0.:1.,scale=5] plot[id=naca] (\x,{0.12/0.2*(0.2969*sqrt(\x )-0.126*\x -0.3516*\x^2 +0.2843*\x^3 -0.1015*\x^4 )}) ;
  \draw[color=blue,domain=0.:.05,yshift=1] plot[id=naca] (\x,{0.12/0.2*(0.2969*sqrt(\x )-0.126*\x -0.3516*\x^2 +0.2843*\x^3 -0.1015*\x^4 )}) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces [image]

Comment: I am not understanding exactly what is it that is "wrong" with the output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The plot is linear between sampling points. To reach a better resolution (and therefore make the plot smoother) use the samples option, i.e.

```
\draw[domain=0.:1.,samples=400] plot[id=naca] (\x,{0.12/0.2*(0.2969*sqrt(\x )-0.126*\x -0.3516*\x^2 +0.2843*\x^3 -0.1015*\x^4 )}) ;
```

You can see the sampling points if you add the `marks=+` (or `*` or `x`, if your prefer). To adjust for your scaling, the size of the markers need to be reduced.

```
\draw[domain=0.:1.,samples=100] plot[id=naca,mark=+,mark size=0.1] (\x,{0.12/0.2*(0.2969*sqrt(\x )-0.126*\x -0.3516*\x^2 +0.2843*\x^3 -0.1015*\x^4 )}) ;
```

Also, instead of using a high sample count, you can supply `smooth` to get a better interpolation algorithm.

You may also want to look at the [pgfplots](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) package.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know how to plot the sampling points ?

Comment: @Sigmun Take a look at my edit.